# Count number of students above and below the average score in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, count, window-functions

I have a sample table below and I am trying to get the number of student above the average score and number of students below the average score.

```
name    subject classroom   classarm    session     first_term_score    first_term_grade
std1    math    nursery 1A  nursery1    2018/2019     90                 A
std2    eng     nursery 1A  nursery1    2018/2019     70                 A
std3    sci     nursery 1A  nursery1    2018/2019     60                 B
std1    eng     nursery 1A  nursery1    2018/2019     64                 B
std2    math    nursery 1A  nursery1    2018/2019     70                 A
```

The target result table is supposed to look like

```
subject   avg_score count_above   count_below
math         80      1                1
eng          65.5    2                0
```

I have been able to write a query to get the names of students above the average score and this can be easily edited to get the count of students below the avg score.

```
SELECT name 
    FROM (SELECT name,
                 AVG(first_term_score) AS average_result
          FROM seveig
          GROUP BY name) sa, 
         (SELECT (AVG(first_term_score)) tavg
          FROM seveig) ta
     WHERE sa.average_result > ta.tavg
```

The issue here is that I want to add the counts in a table indicating the number of students above and below the average score.

If a number is equal to the average score, it can be considered as above the average score.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are running MySQL 8.0, you can use window functions and aggregation:

```
select
    subject,
    avg_score,
    sum(first_term_score >= avg_score) count_above,
    sum(first_term_score <  avg_score) count_below
from (
    select t.*, avg(first_term_score) over(partition by subject) avg_score
    from mytable t
) t
group by subject, avg_score
```

In earlier versions, you can join the table with an aggregate query that computes the average score per subject:

```
select
    t.subject,
    a.avg_score,
    sum(t.first_term_score >= a.avg_score) count_above,
    sum(t.first_term_score <  a.avg_score) count_below
from mytable t
inner join (
    select subject, avg(first_term_score) avg_score
    from mytable
    group by subject
) a on a.subject = t.subject
group by t.subject, a.avg_score
```

---

**Edit**: you appear to be running Big Query, not MySQL as initially tagged. You can use `COUNTIF()`:

```
select
    subject,
    avg_score,
    countif(first_term_score >= avg_score) count_above,
    countif(first_term_score <  avg_score) count_below
from (
    select t.*, avg(first_term_score) over(partition by subject) avg_score
    from mytable t
) t
group by subject, avg_score
```

Comment: how you know it is BigQuery and not mySQL? looks like OP's previous questions are for mySQL too

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant: actually this was discussed in the comments on my answer (that were removed afterwards) - the first queries I provided were raising BQ error message, and OP confirmed that’s what they are running. I then provided a BQ solution, which they accepted.